# Extracting elements from dictionary of list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of list of dictionaries of this format (Yes there are no commas in the 'expected' element).

```
mydict = {
    'labyrinth': [
        {
            u'content': u'something',
            u'expected': u''
        },
        {
            u'content': u'somethingelse',
            u'expected': u'thistext\n   user ID: a.b.c\n      user ID: e.f.g\n'
        },
        {
            u'content': u'blah',
            u'expected': u'a. Path:somepath\n   user ID: b.c.d\n'
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to extract all the user ID's from the above labyrinth.

I tried a few workarounds to minimise the data to this:

```
anodict=mydict['labyrinth'][1].copy() #Just the second dictionary from the list for example
print anodict['expected']
```

Gives me this unicode string :

```
u'a. Path:somepath\n   user ID: b.c.d\n
```

Again I am unsure how to extract the user ID alone from this weird format.
How do I filter only the dictionaries that contain user IDs in the above list of dicts, and , how do I extract the user IDs and their values alone in a separate list of dicts?
Please help.

Comment: Could you update the code you have here so it doesn't throw a syntax error?

Comment: I don't think it's fixed, I was talking about the `mydict` part

Comment: I hope it is fixed now. Can you please remove the downvote?

Comment: The downvote isn't mine..

Comment: I misunderstood.Sorry.The syntax is fixed can you please check it now @koukouviou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample data above is not correct in syntax.

So here is mine updated:

```
mydict = {
    'labyrinth': [
        {
            u'content': u'something',
            u'expected': u''
        },
        {
            u'content': u'somethingelse',
            u'expected': u'thistext\n   user ID: a.b.c\n      user ID: e.f.g\n'
        },
        {
            u'content': u'blah',
            u'expected': u'a. Path:somepath\n   user ID: b.c.d\n'
        }
    ]
}
```

Get any dict object from list index. e.g: 2

```
>>> anodict=mydict['labyrinth'][2]
```

Now import `re` to match id in string

```
>>> import re
>>> anodict
{u'content': u'blah', u'expected': u'a. Path:somepath\n   user ID: b.c.d\n'}
>>> re.search(r'ID\:\s([\w\.]+)', anodict['expected']).group(1)
u'b.c.d'
```

Here `u'b.c.d'` is the result you want.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Vinay.Did you try running the updated code? I fixed its syntax error. ANyway, your code works well. But is there any way you can get a list of user IDs without anodict directly from mydict?

Comment: Because we dont know in advance which dicts contain user IDs and which dont

Comment: @Tania you can do this you self. Just give another try! You're asking here to get a complete working code instead support to fix errors.

Comment: No I just wanted to know if there's a way to check which dict has user ID. Thanks anwyay.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer won't necessarily find multiple ids in a line.

You can use re.findall to pull multiple ids out of the string

```
import re
ids = []
for dict_ in mydict["labyrinth"]:
    ids.extend(re.findall(r"ID: (\w\.\w.\w)", dict_["expected"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question was:

> ...how do I extract the user IDs and their values alone in a separate
>   list of dicts?

Here is some non-regex code that will actually produce your required list of dictionaries:

```
mydict = {'labyrinth': [{u'content': u'something', u'expected': u''},
                        {u'content': u'somethingelse', u'expected': u'thistext\n   user ID: a.b.c\n      user ID: e.f.g\n'},
                        {u'content': u'blah', u'expected': u'a. Path:somepath\n   user ID: b.c.d\n'}]}

ids = []
for d in mydict['labyrinth']:
    expected = d.get('expected', '').split()
    ids.extend([{'user_id': expected[i+1]} for i, s in enumerate(expected) if s == 'ID:'])

print ids
```

**Output**

```
[{'user_id': u'a.b.c'}, {'user_id': u'e.f.g'}, {'user_id': u'b.c.d'}]
```

The above is a slightly tighter version of this:

```
ids = []
for d in mydict['labyrinth']:
    expected = d.get('expected', '').split()
    for i, s in enumerate(expected):
        if s == 'ID:':
            ids.append({'user_id:': expected[i+1]})

print ids
```